# Subtree merge with specific commit

Tags: git, git-subtree

Following the [GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge), how would I do something like this?

```
git read-tree --prefix=somedir/ -u someproject/commit-id:somedir
```

What I want is not to work with the master or any other branch, but a specific commit.

Comment: git read-tree --prefix=somedir/ -u 360dde47f3:somedir?

Comment: I have a related question though. Why do I not need to specify the project. Is it because this id is unique? Where in the manual do I find this?

Comment: Yes, id is unique for your tree state so there is no need to specify the projects. The sha1 hash is enough to identify the complete tree!

Comment: Added answer so it will be easier for people to find it (instead of my comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git read-tree --prefix=somedir/ -u 360dde47f3:somedir
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, if the commit is tagged you can also use the tagname instead of the commit sha1 hash. (e.g. 2.0:somedir)